# How to order resources from a specific module?

Tags: module, redmine, puppet

I got some trouble ordering resources from a module.

```
class { 'postgres' :
    charset => 'UTF8',
    locale => 'fr_FR',
    require => Service['postgresqld'],
}->
class { 'postgresql::server':
}

postgresql::role { 'role1' :
    namevar => 'redmine',
    password_hash => 'random_md5',
    createdb => true,
    require => Class['postgres'],
}

postgresql::database_user {'charly':
    password => 'random',
    role => 'redmine',
    require => postgresql::role['role1'],
}
```

I want to order this, but it appears to have a syntax error on the last line at `role`.
I'm pretty sure it comes from the capitalized first letter. But Puppet doesn't want to run the manifest if I put a capital letter `Postgresql::role['role1]` or `postgresql::Role['role1]`. Without capital letter, I "just" get a warning :

> warning: Deprecation notice:  Resource references should now be capitalized on line 61 in file /home/charly/testManifests/part1.pp

I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. I searched for an answer on the Internet but can't find what I want neither in tutorials nor on the forums.

Comment: How about `require => Postgresql::Role["role1"]` ?

Comment: That's that. Thank you. I don't you why I didn't think about it earlier !

Answer (score 0):

Try using chaining arrows to your resource group references e.g.

```
Class['postgres'] -> Class['postgresql::server']

class { 'postgres' :
   charset => 'UTF8',
   locale  => 'fr_FR',
   require => Service['postgresqld']
}        

class { 'postgresql::server': }
```

More detail can be found here in the puppet reference [Chaining Arrows](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_relationships.html#chaining-arrows)